# Как передать дополнительную model во Modal view в Asp.net Core 2.0?

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Подскажите, как можно передать дополнительную `model` во `Modal view`

имеет 2 таблицы, образно, на страницу Create передается `@model base.Accounts`

вызывается

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    await ConfigureSelectedList();
    return View();
}
```

в котором реализовано заполнение полей (`Login`, `pass`, и т.д.) и имеется выпадающий список пользователей `SelectList.EmployeeId`

на странице имеется кнопка, которая вызывает появление Модального окна для быстрого добавления пользователя в таблицу `Employee` (ФИО + ДР, отдел и т.д.)

как передать модель `@model base.Employee` в `ModalView`, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Добавить" в `ModalView` шло обращение к контроллеру

на примере функции

```
function btnSaveAddEmployee() {
    $.post('/Accounts/_AddEmployee', **как то отправить модель из ModalView**);
}
```

в контроллере

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> _AddEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    var result = new Employee
    {
        FirstName = employee.FirstName
    };
    await _db.Employees.AddAsync(result);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: _Ну и зачем тут метка EF? Дело же в отправке запроса с вьюхи в контроллер или нет?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте js-объект, который будет совпадать (название полей) с моделью, например:

```
var parameters = {
    CoefficientA: $('#coefficient-a').val(),
    CoefficientB: $('#coefficient-b').val(),
    CoefficientC: $('#coefficient-c').val(),
    Step: $('#step').val(),
    RangeFrom: $('#range-from').val(),
    RangeTo: $('#range-to').val()
};
```

Затем отправьте Ajax запрос с этим объектом:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Computing/CalculationData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: parameters,
    success: drawingGraph,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#loader').show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('#loader').hide();
    }
});
```

Если надо перейти куда-то или обновить страницу, то после успешной отправки запроса используйте `window.location.href`.

---

**UPDATE:**

```
<button onclick="AddEmployee()">Добавить</button>


function AddEmployee() {
    var employee = {
        // Собираем инфу с полей в html
        FirstName: $('#fname').val(),
        LastName: $('#lname').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Accounts/_AddEmployee',
        type: 'POST',
        data: employee
    });
}
```

Comment: А можно на примере JavaScript желательно приближенный к моему примеру, например чтобы вставить в таблицу Eployee новую строку где FistName, LastName

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров Что вам непонятно в моём примере? Я то обновил ответ, но я всё равно не знаю что у вас твориться во вьюхе.